# Unit test with controller parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC4 project with Azure. I want to write simple test to check user login. My Login action is defined as

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)) 
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\")) 
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else 
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and my test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void UserValidLoginTest()
{
    // Arrange
    AccountController controller = new AccountController();

    // Act
    LogOnModel model = new LogOnModel()
    {
        UserName = "user@example.com",
        Password = "pass1234"
    };

    var result = controller.LogOn(model, null) as RedirectToRouteResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.RouteValues["action"], "Index");
}
```

I have 2 problems, first is that

```
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

return NullReferenceException and also

```
    Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)
```

does the same. How could I solve this? How could I test it? I could also write integration test with Selenium or Moq, but I'm not sure how to test it with Azure. Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Comment: Testing static classes is hard. Can you use interfaces for those objects? Then mock the interfaces.

Comment: Can we do an example? I dont find any useful example how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to create mocks for the FormsAuthentication & Url Classes. Since it seems like these are static methods, then you should wrap their usage with an interface that will call them, and in the tests, just use a mock class that also implements the same interface, but will return the mocked results you need for the test to run.
(more information on mocking static methods [here](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2011/03/mocking-static-methods-for-unit-testing.html))

This is much easier to do if you're using an IoC container to inject the controller's dependencies, like Windsor Castle.
(You can read about windsor castle container [here](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx))